# Why am I getting this TypeError - "can't convert Symbol into Integer"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes. Each entry looks like this:

```
- !map:Hashie::Mash 
  name: Connor H Peters
  id: "506253404"
```

I'm trying to create a second array, which contains just the id values.

```
["506253404"]
```

This is how I'm doing it

```
second_array = first_array.map { |hash| hash[:id] }
```

But I'm getting this error

```
TypeError in PagesController#home
can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

If I try

```
second_array = first_array.map { |hash| hash["id"] }
```

I get

```
TypeError in PagesController#home
can't convert String into Integer
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using Hashie, which isn't the same as Hash from ruby core. Looking at the [Hashie github](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) repo, it seems that you can access hash keys as methods:

```
first_array.map { |hash| hash.id }
```

Try this out and see if that works--make sure that it doesn't return the object_id. As such, you may want to double-check by doing `first_array.map { |hash| hash.name }` to see if you're really accessing the right data.

Then, provided it's correct, you can use a proc to get the id (but with a bit more brevity):

```
first_array.map(&:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like inside the map block that hash is not actually a hashie - it's an array for some reason.

The result is that the [] method is actually an array accessor method and requires an integer. Eg. hash[0] would be valid, but not hash["id"].

You could try:

```
first_array.flatten.map{|hash| hash.id}
```

which would ensure that if you do have any nested arrays that nesting is removed.

Or perhaps

```
first_array.map{|hash| hash.id if hash.respond_to?(:id)}
```

But either way you may end up with unexpected behaviour.